# Appending multiple dataframes in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, append, concatenation

I have the following dataframe, which is called df_galletas:

[image]

I want to concatenate multiple dataframes from a for loop, which divides a dataframe (df_galletas) into various subdataframes (df_product) based on unique names from a column (producto). The code looks like this:

```
n_steps = 15

estimados = []
df_estimado = pd.DataFrame()

for producto,df_product in df_galletas.groupby(by='producto'):
  endog_train = df_product['Ventas']
  exog_train = df_product.iloc[:, 2:24]
  
  exog_test = df_test

  p = int(df_product['p'].iat[0])
  q = int(df_product['q'].iat[0])
  P = int(df_product['P'].iat[0])
  Q = int(df_product['Q'].iat[0])



  best_model = SARIMAX(endog=endog_train, exog=exog_train, order=(p,0,q), seasonal_order=(P,0,Q,7), simple_differencing=False, trend = "c", 
                         enforce_stationarity=False) 
  best_model_fit = best_model.fit(disp=False)

  forecast = best_model_fit.get_forecast(exog= exog_test, steps=n_steps).summary_frame()['mean']

  
  estimados.append([ producto, forecast.index,forecast.values])
  df_estimados = pd.DataFrame(estimados) 
  df_estimados.columns = ['producto','fecha','forecast']

  data = {
  "fecha": forecast.index ,
  "forecast": forecast.values,
            }

  df_forecast = pd.DataFrame(
        data = forecast.values,
        index = forecast.index,
        columns = ['forecast'] 

    )
  df_forecast['producto'] = producto
                      


df_estimado = pd.concat([df_forecast], axis = 0)
```

In **estimados** I store the values of the forecast from every product, with each date, and it can be seen like this:

[image]

Before creating the single dataframe, I used an append, which creates a list mentioned before, and then I convert ir to a dataframe defining a column called product which repeats the values 15 times, as it has 15 values each subdataframe.

Then, to create the single dataframe of every product of the loop, I tried using a concat, as it is shown in the last line code. I think the identation syntax is ok.

The problem is that when I visualize the table it only shows the last product which was iterated:

[image]

I am stuck in this part and I need a huge help on this, if anyone can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not making a list of data frames. Try initiating a list like `dfs = []` before the for loop and using `dfs.append(df_forecast)` just like you did for `estimados`. Then call `pd.concat(dfs)` after the for loop. Example below

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = []
for i in range(5):
    this_data = {'A': [i, i+1]}
    this_df = pd.DataFrame(this_data)
    dfs.append(this_df)
full_df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: I follow your steps, defining, `dfs = []` before loop, then  `dfs.append(df_forecast)` in the loop, then `dfs = pd.DataFrame(dfs) `  but I have the following error: **Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 15, 2)**

Comment: Replace `dfs = pd.DataFrame(dfs)` with `dfs = pd.concat(dfs)`

Comment: Now this error:  **first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"**

Comment: Somehow you are not creating the list of dataframes properly because `dfs` end up as a single dataframe by the end of your loop instead of a list of dataframes.

Comment: I tried with the correct identation but I do not see the mistake.

Comment: It's done! Thank you so much!  This is the final code. I think the problem now was in the concat putting it as a list but obviously was wrong, because is a dataframe. Now solved!